# want to create a family tree from a Laravel nested Relation

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to create a family tree

Person Table have `id` and `name` and `birth` and `father_id` and `mother_id`
The Person Model is self-relevant

```
//In Person Model
public function father()
{
    $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'father_id', 'id');
}

public function mother()
{
    $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'mother_id', 'id');
}
```

So It can be used in this way.

```
$person = Person::find(1);
$person->father->name;
$person->mother->name;
$person->father->mother->name;
```

I was able to get, but I don't know how to display it.
I want to display it using foreach. Or, another way to write neatly.

I want the layout to look like this
https://jsfiddle.net/tp1Lumkx/1/

but This layout is very long and contains a lot of overlapping places.

so want to use foreach.
or Using Blade's `include` and recursive and so on.
I want to keep it short and show it.

```
example)

foreach($person as $p){
<tr colspan="?">{{$p->name}}</tr>

}
@include('father_col')
```

controller

```
public function show($person_id)
{
    $person = Person::find($person_id);
    return view('familytree',compact('person'));
}
```

`familytree`
It was too hard to fill it all up and I failed.
so want to use foreach.
or Using Blade's `include` and so on.
I want to keep it short and show it.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="p-0">Own</th>
            <th class="p-0">1 generation</th>
            <th class="p-0">2 generation</th>
            <th class="p-0">3 generation</th>
            <th class="p-0">4 generation</th>
            <th class="p-0" colspan="2">5 generation</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="32">{{ $person->name }}</td>
            <td rowspan="16">{{ $person->father->name }}</td>
            <td rowspan="8">{{ $person->father->father->name }}</td>
            <td rowspan="4">{{ $person->father->father->father->name }}</td>
            <td rowspan="2">{{ $person->father->father->father->father->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $person->father->father->father->father->father->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $person->father->father->father->father->father->birth}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $person->father->father->father->father->mother->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $person->father->father->father->father->mother->birth}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">{{ $person->father->father->father->mother->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $person->father->father->father->mother->father->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $person->father->father->father->mother->father->birth}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $person->father->father->father->mother->mother->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $person->father->father->father->mother->mother->birth}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">{{ $person->father->father->mother->name }}</td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="8"></td>
            <td rowspan="4"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        
            <td rowspan="16">{{ $person->mother->name }}</td>
            <td rowspan="8">{{ $person->mother->father->name }}</td>
            <td rowspan="4">{{ $person->mother->father->father->name }}</td>
            <td rowspan="2">{{ $person->mother->father->father->father->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $person->mother->father->father->father->father->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $person->mother->father->father->father->father->birth}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $person->mother->father->father->father->mother->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $person->mother->father->father->father->mother->birth}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">{{ $person->mother->father->father->mother->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $person->mother->father->father->mother->father->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $person->mother->father->father->mother->father->birth}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $person->mother->father->father->mother->mother->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $person->mother->father->father->mother->mother->birth}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">{{ $person->mother->father->mother->name }}</td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="8"></td>
            <td rowspan="4"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

My English is not good.
So, if you cant understand, sorry

Thank you

Comment: So simple `{{ $person->father->name }}` But you dont need foreach for this one row.

Comment: sorry, i want to build that layout simply.That's what I wanted to say.

Comment: Paste your layout code and controller code with your question

Comment: thnaks, i done. code is too long. sorry

Answer (score 0):

The self::class is supposed to be the model of the related table

//In Person Model

```
use App\Father;
use App\Mother;

public function father() { 
   $this->belongsTo(Father::class, 'father_id', 'id');
  //$this->belongsTo(self::class, 'father_id', 'id');
 } 
public function mother() { 
  $this->belongsTo(Mother::class, 'mother_id', 'id');
  //$this->belongsTo(self::class, 'mother_id', 'id');
 }
```

//In Father model

```
use App\Person;

public function person(){
  $this->hasOne(Person::class);
}
```

//In Mother model

```
use App\Person;

public function person(){
  $this->hasOne(Person::class);
}
```

I hope this help.. you can still check this link
`https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships`